# Replace character string part

Tags: qgis

Ly layer has an attribute containing paths:

```
'\\aaa\bbb\c\d1',
'\\aaa\bbb\c\d2',
'\\aaa\bbb\c\d3',
...
```

I just want to update 'part of the paths' replace `aaa\bbb` with `A.a.i\d-0\doc_1`

I tried with the `replace` command the result cuts off the end of the path and doesn't seem to support dots.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Try replace with 'A.a.i\\d-0\\doc_1'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Answer (score 6):

`\` is the escape character, meaning the following character will be used/printed as it is (for example it lets you have a string containing quotes such as `'I\'m here'`. If you want to match or use the `\` character, you would have to escape it by prepending another `\`

Do this both for the text to be replaced and for the replacement:

`replace(columnName,'aaa\\bbb','A.a.i\\d-0\\doc_1')`

[image]